# TinyMCE: How to prepend 'http://' to URL if it's not there

Tags: http, url, tinymce

Is there way to prepend 'http://' to URL if it's not there while adding URL with Insert Link in TinyMCE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you would need to copy the tinymce Insert Link plugin, rename it, add the necessary code to it (the "http"-Adding) and use it as your own plugin.

**EDIT:**  Ok, here is an example (using jQuery):

```
// You might need to change the event and/or tha handling 
// but this should give you a guess at what needs to be done
setup : function(ed)
{
       ed.onClick.add(function(ed, evt)
       {
           $(ed.getBody()).find('a').each(function(index, element){
               if (!$(this).attr('href').search('http')){
                    $(this).attr('href', 'http://' + $(this).attr('href'));
               }
           });
       });
},
```

Comment: Thanks Thariama. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You could use the setup parameter or an own plugin to implement a handler which listens on a specified event. This handler could search the content for link and check if they have "http" set.

Comment: Thanks again, could you please post some sample code to how to do that? I'll be obliged for your favor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your effort writing code for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this problem as well with version 4.x. I discovered that the `link` plugin supports an option that prompts the user to add the protocol. But unfortunately it's not mentioned in the documentation, it's only documented in the changelog so I would imagine this is widely unknown.

```
$('textarea').tinymce({
    ...
    link_assume_external_targets: true
    ...
});
```

[image]

Comment: This helped. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an option to skip this alert and force adding http:// to all links without http/https?

Comment: As far as I am aware back when I researched this, no. Things may have changed though.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by prepopulating the field value with 'http://' in the tinymce insertLink.aspx file.

```
<ui:PropertyPanel runat="server" Text="Url">
   <input type="hidden" id="localUrl" name="localUrl" onchange="" />
   <input id="href" name="href" type="text" style="width: 220px;" value="http://" onchange="document.getElementById('localUrl').value = ''; 
selectByValue(this.form,'linklisthref',this.value);" />
</ui:PropertyPanel>
```

**value="http://"**

Answer (score 0):

in link.js, find "if (!f.href.value)"

add an "else" clause

```
    else {
        var href = f.href.value;
        if (href.indexOf('http') == -1) {
            href = 'http://' + href;
            f.href.value = href;
        }
    }
```

** remember that you did that in case you update your tinymce component!

Answer (score -1):

i just saw this and it might help, version 5:

link_assume_external_targets: [option];

you can use the option "https" or "http" and it should not prompt

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/link/#link_assume_external_targets