# TinyMCE appends links to the current URL

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm running into this weird issue with TinyMCE where selecting a text and adding a link to it without "http://" will cause the new link to append to the current URL.

Example (assume my website is www.example.com):

[image]

Now under my settings "click" will link to "www.example.com/linkexample.com". I need it to link to "http://linkexample.com" instead, without manually adding "http://" in the "Url" field in the popup.

I've been trying different solutions online but nothing seemed to work for me.

Here is the list of solutions I've tried so far, none worked for me:

- [TinyMCE: How to prepend 'http://' to URL if it's not there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061409/tinymce-how-to-prepend-http-to-url-if-its-not-there)
- All examples from : http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/url_conversion.php

P.S. I'm running the latest TinyMCE 4.1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm done to try this one. it's worked for me (tell me if this thing
    worked for you)

1. Go to link plugin on tinymce (tinymce/plugins/link)
2. Edit this file plugin.min.js (tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js)
3. Find `www` using Ctrl+F in your editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text
4. You will get this code `/^\s*www\./i` delete `www\.`
5. Now your code become `/^\s*i`
6. Now Save it. Done
7. Refresh your code using TinyMCE.
8. Now try use linkexample.com, You will get notification to add prefix http://

**Done. I hope help you out.**

Answer (score 1):

In version 4.x this functionality is built in. But unfortunately it's not mentioned in the documentation, it's only documented in the changelog so I would imagine this is widely unknown.

```
$('textarea').tinymce({
    ...
    link_assume_external_targets: true
    ...
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I actually replaced this code:

/^\s*www./i.test(e)

with

!(/^\s*(http://|https://)/i.test(e))